# change registration submit value in buddypress plugin

Tags: buddypress

i want to change Complete Sign Up to other value in buddypress plugin. I am changing  in registration page which are located in bp_theme/register/register.php . But its show previous value. Please how can i do...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is just removed or comment the register.php file code and put new development for simple create new registration form code but here the problem is you have followed the Buddypress rules is the custom form data are stored same as Buddypress. This is an easy way to finish and fulfill all your requirements.